# Creo que no me está tomando correctamente el valor del array en google apps script

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Lo que intento hacer es pushear un array dentro de otro array. Esto lo uso para poder hacer una tabla para visualizarlo en un Chart dentro de una Google Apps Script.

Aquí la función.

```
function getSpreadsheetDataContenidosGs() {
var ssID = "1QhfnzfcH_dKiOdXV6b5HEyAHn4biGCzzSt11LXlHnlE",
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheets()[0];
var maximoFilas = sheet.getLastRow();
var dataContenidos = sheet.getRange("A1:C" + maximoFilas).getValues();
var columnaGrupo = buscarGrupo();
var columnaAgregada = sheet.getRange(columnaGrupo + "1:" + columnaGrupo).getValues();
var array = [];
var agregado = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= dataContenidos.length; i++) {
    array = dataContenidos[i];
    agregado = columnaAgregada[i][0];
    array.push(agregado);
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me tira un error que dice:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined (line 168, file "Code")

La linea 168 es esta:  `agregado = columnaAgregada[i][0];`

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que has puesto menor o igual que en la condición del bucle for (`i <= dataContenidos.length`). Esto es debido a que como los indices de los miembros de un Array son base cero el último indice es el tamaño del Array menos uno.

Cambia

```
for (var i = 0; i <= dataContenidos.length; i++) {
```

por

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataContenidos.length; i++) {
```